# Weyl Semimetal and Dirac semimetal

Tags: weyl-semimetal

How to distinguish between a Weyl semimetal and a Dirac semimetal? Which calculations are required to check their existence? Which codes can be used?

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few thoughts:

#### Weyl semimetal

**Weyl point.** A Weyl point is a point at which 2 bands cross. This places severe constraints on which type of material can host Weyl points, because in materials with both time-reversal and inversion symmetries, bands are already doubly-degenerate (spin up and down have the same energy at every $\mathbf{k}$-point), so all band crossings will involve 4 (rather than 2) bands and will therefore *not* be Weyl points. This means that a prerequisite to have a Weyl point is that the material breaks time reversal symmetry (e.g. ferromagnet), or inversion symmetry. The latter futher requires that there is a spin-dependent term in the Hamiltonian to actually split the spin degeneracy of the bands (as inversion symmetry breaking alone is not spin dependent), which can be accomplished with spin-orbit coupling.

**Weyl semimetal.** A Weyl semimetal is simply a material that has a Weyl point at (or very near) the Fermi energy.

**Characterization.** A Weyl point is a source or sink (monopole) of Berry curvature, so you can characterize a Weyl point by constructing a surface in $\mathbf{k}$-space that encloses the Weyl point, and then calculating the Chern number over that surface. It will be $+1$ or $-1$ for Weyl points, and the sign is called the chirality of the Weyl point.

**Codes.** Most codes that allow you to calculate topological properties can be used to characterize Weyl points. For example, [Z2Pack](http://z2pack.ethz.ch) or [WannierTools](http://www.wanniertools.com), both of which have interfaces with some of the major DFT codes.

#### Dirac semimetal

A Dirac semimetal is similar to a Weyl semimetal, but now the crossing involves four bands rather than two. This means that the symmetry breaking conditions are not as severe, and a well-known example of a material that hosts Dirac points is graphene. In fact, the very presence of Dirac points in graphene is protected by time-reversal and inversion symmetry (see [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-to-understand-the-time-reversal-symmetry-of-graphene/1602#1602)).